# Update the column in case of duplicate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am storing some config values in my table which looks like

```
name   value 
secret  1223
url     "url"
```

Now I have a situation where I want to update the `secret` keys value column in case if the user re inserts it ,or allow any other config values to be inserted properly

like say
INSERT INTO table (name,value) Values('secret',"new secret");
so the table should look like

```
name   value 
secret  1223
url     "new secret"
```

But if I do something like

INSERT INTO table (name,value) Values('new attribute',"value");

```
  name   value 
    secret  1223
    url     "new secret"
    new attribute  "value"
```

A new row gets added

I tried  this

```
  INSERT INTO table (name,value) Values('secret',"new secret"); ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES(value)
```

But thats not working

Answer (score 0):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` might be worked on unique or primary key constraints on a table.

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs.

if we insert a new row which create unique or primary key constraints it might be worked

BTW I think the script might be like this, the semicolon need to put at last

```
INSERT INTO table (name,value) Values('secret',"new secret") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES(value);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d4ff67aceae328be0250f70f96ae20ba)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it didn't work because of syntax errors.

This should be working fine

```
INSERT INTO table (name,value) Values('secret','new secret') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES('new secret')
```

[db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKf8Lg2gpEdCbgfUWgRYm1/1)